# PHP Working with an array to find ranges and missing numbers

Tags: php, range

I have an array that looks like this:

```
    [0] => Array
    (
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 4
        [3] => 3
        [5] => 1
        [7] => 1
        [8] => 2
        [9] => 3
        [10] => 4
        [11] => 5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [1] => 6
        [2] => 5
        [4] => 3
        [5] => 2
        [6] => 1
        [8] => 3
        [9] => 4
        [10] => 5
        [11] => 6
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [1] => 7
        [2] => 6
        [3] => 5
        [4] => 4
        [5] => 3
        [6] => 2
        [7] => 3
        [8] => 4
        [11] => 7
    )
```

I have an order of operations I'm trying to go through and I really don't know where to go from here. Any suggestions would be of great help.

1. First I give my class the number of items I want to return. For example here we'll use 4.
2. I want to loop through and find the item in the array that has the lowest value.
3. I want to look at the keys to the items around (it included) and be sure they're not missing a number if they are..reject it..

In this example the first one you would come to would be:

```
    [5] => 1
```

Now looking around it you see that the keys are missing some numbers. So no combination of 4 will get that to match any 4 in the proper order.

```
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 3
    [5] => 1  //this one
    [7] => 1
    [8] => 2
    [9] => 3
```

In this situation I want it to move onto the next case.

```
    [7] => 1
```

Notice this one will work due to the keys being 7,8,9,10.

```
    [7] => 1
    [8] => 2
    [9] => 3
    [10] => 4
```

This is what I would like returned first..but I don't even know how to begin to get there.

Further more there are situations like this..Say for example there are no 1's at all in the dataset..and only this lone 2 in the last one.

```
    [0] => Array
    (
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 4
        [3] => 3
        [5] => 3
        [7] => 3
        [8] => 3
        [9] => 3
        [10] => 4
        [11] => 5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [1] => 6
        [2] => 5
        [4] => 3
        [5] => 3
        [6] => 3
        [8] => 3
        [9] => 4
        [10] => 5
        [11] => 6
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [1] => 7
        [2] => 6
        [5] => 3
        [6] => 2 // this one
        [7] => 3
        [8] => 4
        [11] => 7
    )
```

The following wont work:

```
    [6] => 2 // this one
    [7] => 3
    [8] => 4
    [11] => 7
```

but this one will:

```
        [5] => 3
        [6] => 2 // this one
        [7] => 3
        [8] => 4
```

I  have no idea on how to approach this.. If someone could offer some advice it would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "missing a number" - in your example, `[6]` is missing too, but `[7]` is accepted. Presumably if it's about to accept, say, `[7]`, then the following x must exist?

Comment: Yes! If it's going to accept 7. Then I would want 4,5,6 to exist.. or 5,6,8..or 8,9,10...given that my initial input is only looking for 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes your data is in an array called `$data`. I'll describe it in steps, then pull it all together as a function.

**Step 1** find the min value:

```
$minValue=min($data);
```

**Step 2** loop through the array looking for all values that are that value:

```
foreach($data as $index => $value){

    if($value == $minValue){
         // $index is a candidate!
    }
}
```

**Step 3** Check if `$valuesToReturn` entries exist after index:

```
    $success=true;

    for($i=1;$i<=$valuesToReturn;$i++){

        if(!array_key_exists($index + $i,$data)){

            // Candidate failed.
            $success=false;
            break;

        }

    }
```

**Step 4** If the candidate was successful, return it.

```
    if($success){
        return $index;
    }
```

Putting that all together, we get this:

```
function findSuitableIndex($data,$valuesToReturn){

    // Min:
    $minValue=min($data);

    foreach($data as $index => $value){

        if($value == $minValue){
            // $index is a candidate!

            // test if index is actually suitable:
            $success=true;

            for($i=1;$i<=$valuesToReturn;$i++){

               if(!array_key_exists($index + $i,$data)){

                    // Candidate failed.
                    $success=false;
                    break;

                }

            }

            if($success){
                return $index;
            }

        }

    }

    // If we fell down here, we failed to find any successful results.
    return -1;
}
```

Working sample:

[Code on eval.in](https://eval.in/678990)

Comment: WOW! You are my hero!!!! Now I just need to make it return the working 4 results in an array. I suggest everyone thumbs up this right now because it's perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JoelHasSimpleQuestions no problem! I just quickly re-read the question so one thing that might catch you out: if `$valuesToReturn` is 4, then it'll check the 4 entries after the 'candidate' index. Change `$i<=$valuesToReturn` to `$i<$valuesToReturn` if you only want it to check the following 3 :) To return an array, the easiest thing to do is copy/paste that same for loop and do e.g. `$result[]=$data[$index+$i];`

Comment: @JoelHasSimpleQuestions My personal choice would be to do that last part in a separate function too - that way you can get just the index if it's useful.

Comment: Ok Awesome!!!!!! My hero. Big time. Any suggestions on finding 5,6,8? That's kind of the part where I'm really confused now.

Comment: @JoelHasSimpleQuestions how do you mean? I.e. what's it got to search for? :)

Comment: If I've found my candidate and the key is 7. 5,6,8 would be what I want returned. In the event 9 is missing or 4 is missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128282/discussion-between-luke-briggs-and-joel-has-simple-questions).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions. Your exact implementation would depend on your particular situation.

To loop through each element in the array, you could use a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach ($arr[0] as $index => $value) {
    // Here, $arr[0][$index] == $value;

}
```

To check if a key exists or not, you could use `array_key_exists`.

```
if ( !array_key_exists($index - 1, $arr[0]) ) {
    // The previous index is missing in the array.

}
```

A simple (but inefficient) way to find a contiguous sequence of `k` indices with the smallest value at the first index would be to find the smallest element and check if the contiguous sequence exists; if not, find the next smallest element and recursively check until you have completed processing the largest element.

You could also try finding all contiguous sequences of at least length `k` and then selecting the sequence with the smallest value at the first index.

Hope this helps!